# Copiar pass al portapapeles

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Nada más iniciar mi pagina cuando imprimo la tabla de datos, en el campo de la contraseña lo que imprimo son ****** para ocultar la contraseña, para mostrarla tengo lo siguiente:

Tengo un

```
@Ajax.ActionImage(@"~/Content/images/eye.png", "Mostrar Contraseña", "RequestPassword", "Credential", parameters, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.ContainerName })
```

Lo que no consigo es que con

```
input type=image src="~/Content/images/copy.png" class="btn" data-clipboard-text="@Model.Password" title="Copiar Contraseña"

script type="text/javascript"
   new Clipboard('.btn');
script
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que si pulso el botón de copiar me copie la contraseña pero no lo consigo debido a que me copia los **** pero si le doy al botón de ver contraseña y luego al de copiar si que me copia.

Comment: porque no usas un campo contraseña en lugar de un input en la parte del html?

Comment: El campo contraseña es un textbox porque estoy trabajando con asp.net MVC